# While loop does not end

Tags: python

Hi can someone tell me why this doesn't work? It runs on forever and doesn't end. When the a value reaches 10 it should exit the loop.

```
a=0
while a!=10:
    for counter in range(11):
        a+=counter
        print a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` becomes `10` while it is still inside of the `for` loop (and gets larger than `10` when the `while` loop goes for a second run).

Move your `print` down one level and you'll see what I mean:

```
a=0
while a!=10:
    for counter in range(11):
        a+=counter
    print a
    raw_input('press enter to keep looping')
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't know that the a value would only be checked after the for loop has ended. I thought it would be checked every occurrence in the for loop. Python newbie :$

Answer (score 1):

After first for loop it becomes 55, and it is not equal to 10 and it keeps increase

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean:

```
a=0
for counter in range(11):
    a+=counter
    print a
    if a > 10: 
        break
```

you can give a look at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 0):

Because counter is increasing, and A is therefore going up bby more!
so instead of a equalling 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc, it equals 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, etc! 
just go a+= 1
or change it to "while a<10"

Comment: if you want to print the numbers 0 to ten, go:
while a<= 10
    print a